# How is a file directly attached to a program for getting data?

Tags: c++, linux, powershell, unix

I need to understand what is the effect of

`$ ./program.out < input_data.txt > output_file.txt` (linux/UNIX)

and the similar

`Get-Content input.txt | .\program.exe > output.txt` (Powershell)

How is information from a file directly sent to the program?

Also, how does a c++ program without any code to get input from somewhere reads from a file that is passed to it as shown in the code above. All I have seen is `<iostream>` and `<cstdio>` libraries included in the code.

Comment: It's called input and output redirection. The contents of `input_data.txt` or `input.txt` are being sent to `std::cin`, and the contents of `std::cout` are being sent to `output_file.txt` or `output.txt`, respectively.

Comment: how does it happen? does the os attach the file contents to std::cin? also as I said, there is no code related to input/output except importing libraries iostream and cstdio

Comment: The OS doesn't do it. The shell does it. It opens the file and then duplicates the resulting file descriptor onto cin. In other words, it makes cin point to the file instead of stdin. The program knows nothing about the redirection. It just reads cin as normal.

Comment: There is a difference in case of PowerShell. Input / output is not directly attached to a file handle. Instead PowerShell interprets the file as text and does line-based processing. Because of this, PowerShell cannot redirect binary streams in a straightforward way (it's possible only by using "low-level" .NET code). See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908

Comment: @kaylum  You mean instead of console.  It's still stdin.